# How to test TS7805 regulator if it is working?

Tags: integrated-circuit, test

I have a TS7805 voltage regulator that was placed on a pcb, laying around for 2 yeras. Is there a fast way to see if it is still working? I have a multimeter and some resistors at home and an DC 5-12V Adapter.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the heck I got -1? would be nice to see an explanation!

Comment: @Whoever downvoted - yes, and I've said this already several times, if you downvote, tell us why. Sean87 may be able to improve his question. Downvoting without explaining looks rather cowardly.

Comment: Actually he got two down votes, with two up votes to bring the total back to 0.  I don't know why either.  The question seems fair enough and not deserving to get dinged in my opinion.  I'm adding one up vote just to cancel one of the down votes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place 12V DC on the input, and check if the output voltage is 5V. If it is, the part is *probably* OK. Next connect a 5\$\Omega\$/5W resistor between output and ground. Still 5V? Most likely OK.

Comment: +1 for the load test. At 12V input the regulator will dissipate 7W however, and thermal protection will quickly become active. Better use a lower input voltage for this test, and mount the 7805 on a heatsink.

Comment: @stevenvh I dont have 5W resistors now :( wat I have are in range of 0.5 to 1 watt, is there a workaround?

Comment: @Federico lucky I had the sink :P

Comment: My experience is that a 1/4W resistor will withstand 1W for a short time, so maybe you can place 5 x 1\$\Omega\$ in series. BTW, it doesn't have to be exactly 1A load, 500mA should give you the same verdict.

Comment: It's working! saved some bucks on my component list for next project :P

Comment: An LM7805 costs 0.45 euro (Mouser)

Answer (score 3):

Apply +7V or higher to pin 1, ground to pin 2, and measure the voltage across pins 2 and 3.

Should give you 5 volts.

See the [Data Sheet](http://193.196.117.25/info-ss09/e_kart_rekuperation/data/TS7800.pdf)

Comment: It seems you used an IP based link, could you correct that to use a web address so a server change does not break this link?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious thing to do is to apply at least 7.5V to the input and see if you get 5V on the output.  You should be able to vary the input voltage from about 7.5V to up to what your supply can put out or the 7805 can withstand.